# Setting up a local network

Tags: networking, ubuntu-12.04

I have an old computer with two network cards and I've installed Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS on it. I have an old router d-link des-1024d.

I want to plug the internet into one network card and the router into the other. Then I want to plug 15 work stations into the router and be able to use the internet from the server's internet connection.

Also a bonus would be to allocate each workstation a certain amount of bandwidth and also to be able to block websites.

Also I want to be able to have a mapped network drive on the Win7 machines so they can transfer files to the server as backup.

I need a step by step guide as I don't usually do this.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to setup your Ubuntu machine as a proxy server ...
[Here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/set-proxy-server-ubuntu-linux/) you can find a brief explanation of what's a proxy server and a how to do turn your Ubuntu into a proxy!

Answer (score 0):

You are actually asking 3 different questions here, each requires quite a bit of expertise, and its probably unreasonable to expect step-by-step for each one.  Hopefully the information provided below will suffice to allow you to use Google, as each of these topics has been covered extensively elsewhere.

1. To get routing going, you will probably use IPTables and NAT.  A guide on doing this can be found [here.](http://www.howtoforge.com/nat-gateway-iptables-port-forwarding-dns-and-dhcp-setup-ubuntu-8.10-server)   (Its for an older version, but still applies).
2. Windows File Sharing under Linux is normally done using SAMBA - You can find a howto http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=202605
3. Bandwidth control is the most complex subject.   Look at mossey464's post on 28-04-2100 22:54 [here](https://www.boards.ie/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=2055881767).  To understand how it works, go through [this.](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Traffic-Control-HOWTO/index.html).  The key thing to remember though, is you always want to shape traffic on the outward leg (ie if you are shaping requests from the client to the world, you want to shape the world facing internet on the router, similarly for traffic from the world to the client you want to shape it on the internal interface on the router.

I would avoid the proxy route proposed by IMADJamil - as this will only provide a subset of connectivity, and comes with issues all of its own.